# SQL Server update from GDR to CU-17

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, installation, upgrade

I'm using SQL SERVER 2017 GDR version 14.0.2002.14. I want to upgrade to the latest possible version of SQL Server 2017.

My question is can I download CU-17 and directly run the latest cumulative update which is CU-17 version 14.0.3238.1? OR do I need to reinstall SQL Server 2017 RTM version 14.0.1000.169 first?

Comment: You just need to apply the latest CU.

Comment: Seeing as the Servicing Model for Microsoft SQL Server 2017 has changed, I would propose a re-opening of this question to allow for a version specific answer. This is not a full duplicate of the question it has been closed for.